# How can I get rid off this slight red border in Progress-GUI?

Tags: themes, gui, gtk

Perhaps someone can help me to get rid of this slight red border in the progress-GUI? See the attached screenshot.

[image]

I'm using the [finery theme](http://gnome-look.org/content/show.php/Finery+(improved+Radiance+theme)?content=124694), I found the gtkrc file in my themes folder but doesn't find where to change the color of this border or an possibility to change the borderwidth to zero?

Comment: Which theme are you using? Is the idea that you want to customize the theme, or that you think there is a problem and theme is showing up wrong?

Comment: I'm using the finery theme http://gnome-look.org/content/show.php/Finery+(improved+Radiance+theme)?content=124694 , i found the gtkrc file in my themes folder but doesn't find where to change the color of this border or an possibility to change the borderwidth to zero?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is simply a feature of the theme. You could [edit the gtkrc](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=377397) or change the theme.
Probably just best for you to change the theme if you are unsure. You can use `gedit` to edit the theme. It will usually be in `/usr/share/themes/themename/gtk-2.0/`.

Looking at the theme, the relevant line appears to be line 71:

`GtkEntry::progress-border = { 2, 2, 2, 2 }`

Try changing these values and see if the border goes away (I haven't installed the theme so I cannot verify as yet).

Another potentially relevant set of lines are the lines from 358 to 361:
`style "progressbar"`

`{`
`xthickness = 1`

`ythickness = 1`

Comment: How can i edit the gtkrc?

Comment: I update my answer :)

Comment: thanks Roland, found the file gtkrc file, but doesn't find where to change the color of this border or an possibility to change the borderwidth to zero? Could you assist me?

Comment: I'll take a look at the theme and see if I can make any relevant changes :)

Comment: thanks for your effort. change the border shades value to 0 did the trick: style "progressbar" 
{
    xthickness = 1
    ythickness = 1
    
    engine "murrine"
    {
        border_shades       = { 0, 0} # draw a gradient on the border.